# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method AutoMapper Error

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public async Task<List<ViewTACInputsRepositoryDTO>> GetViewTACInputsRepositoryDTO()
        {
            var items = await _context.ViewTACInputsRepositoryModel.ToListAsync();                 
            var result = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<ViewTACInputsRepositoryDTO>>(items);
            return result;
        }
```

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Mapper.Map<List>(object)'

How can I fix this error.

Comment: The `Mapper.Map()` method isn't static (anymore), you have to create and configure a mapping and use it then. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to call `Map`, you need an instance of `IMapper` which comes from a `MapperConfiguration` instance where you tell AutoMapper what types it needs to handle.

Something like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<<List<ViewTACInputsRepositoryDTO>, <List<ViewTACInputsRepositoryDTO>>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

//Now you can do this
result = mapper.Map<List<ViewTACInputsRepositoryDTO>>(items);
```